# column-fill: auto; no height overflows div

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a container in a container which has multiple ul tags inside which should break into 4 columns. The should fill up from left to right. In Chrome and all the other even on firefox on my iPad this works without setting a pixel amount in the height property. But on my Desktop Firefox the content overflows when the height is set to auto.

```css
.parent {height: 700px;}
.child {column-count: 4;column-fill: auto;height: auto;}
ul {break-inside: avoid; page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        <ul>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
        </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
        </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
        </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
        </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
        </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
        </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
          <li>BLABLABLA</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The child container is then overflowing the parent and do not break into 4 columns.

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `column-fill: auto;`:

(Note:  I added `margin-top: 0;` to the first `ul` to improve the layout / distribution of the columns across the container).

```css
.parent {
  height: 700px;
}

.child {
  column-count: 4;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

ul:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <ul>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
      <li>BLABLABLA</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```